# Common pitfalls in Python

Tags: python

Today I was bitten again by mutable default arguments after many years. I usually don't use mutable default arguments unless needed, but I think with time I forgot about that.  Today in the application I added tocElements=[] in a PDF generation function's argument list and now "Table of Contents" gets longer and longer after each invocation of "generate pdf". :)

What else should I add to my list of things to MUST avoid?

- Always import modules the same way, e.g. `from y import x` and `import x` are [treated as different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459236/module-reimported-if-imported-from-different-path).
- Do not use *range* in place of lists because `range()` will become an iterator anyway, the following will fail:

  ```
    myIndexList = [0, 1, 3]
    isListSorted = myIndexList == range(3)  # will fail in 3.0
    isListSorted = myIndexList == list(range(3))  # will not
  ```

  Same thing can be mistakenly done with *xrange:*

  ```
    myIndexList == xrange(3)
  ```
- Be careful catching multiple exception types:

  ```
    try:
        raise KeyError("hmm bug")
    except KeyError, TypeError:
        print TypeError
  ```

  This prints "hmm bug", though it is not a bug; it looks like we are catching exceptions of both types, but instead we are catching KeyError only as variable *TypeError,* use this instead:

  ```
    try:
        raise KeyError("hmm bug")
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        print TypeError
  ```

Comment: I was more interested in thing which MUST be avoided, looks like there is only one candidate

Comment: I recommend using pylint, it catches a lot of these gotchas.  I use it integrated with eclipse(pydev).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530530/python-2-x-gotchas-and-landmines - isn't this question the original one?

Comment: yes actually it is now, when I started it i wanted to know the answer to a very specific question, things which are MUST avoid and I found only one till now ("mutable default arguments")

Comment: Do use `range()` as a list in Python 2.x. It is a job for 2to3 script to convert it to `list(range())` in Python 3.x

Comment: Use `except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:` syntax to avoid confusion.

Comment: The biggest pitfall in Python is the Python itself. Do not use it. Use a normal programming language. There are plenty of them! But if you have to, then read this post very attentive! :)

Comment: @Narek: What is a "normal" programming language?

Comment: Normal programming language is fast, comfortable, full of features, has lot of libraries, has lot of helps, books, forums and many other internet references. It is easy to learn and easy to use! Normall programing language is the language that while using it you do not dislike it, but you like it more and more!

Comment: It should be in an appropriate level: Not as much high that it restricts lot of important features in order to gain confort and easy of use, and not as much low level (like assembly is) that for writing a simple program you start "to talk to the metal" (I mean hardware), when in majority cases it is not necesarry. Of curse you should also take into consideration your task: for each task, for each aspect you have to give priopity to different programming languages!

Answer (score 73):

**Don't use index to loop over a sequence**

Don't :

```
for i in range(len(tab)) :
    print tab[i]
```

Do :

```
for elem in tab :
    print elem
```

*For* will automate most iteration operations for you.

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) if you really need both the index and the element.

```
for i, elem in enumerate(tab):
     print i, elem
```

**Be careful when using "==" to check against *True* or *False***

```
if (var == True) :
    # this will execute if var is True or 1, 1.0, 1L

if (var != True) :
    # this will execute if var is neither True nor 1

if (var == False) :
    # this will execute if var is False or 0 (or 0.0, 0L, 0j)

if (var == None) :
    # only execute if var is None

if var :
    # execute if var is a non-empty string/list/dictionary/tuple, non-0, etc

if not var :
    # execute if var is "", {}, [], (), 0, None, etc.

if var is True :
    # only execute if var is boolean True, not 1

if var is False :
    # only execute if var is boolean False, not 0

if var is None :
    # same as var == None
```

**Do not check if you can, just do it and handle the error**

Pythonistas usually say "It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission".

Don't :

```
if os.path.isfile(file_path) :
    file = open(file_path)
else :
    # do something
```

Do :

```
try :
    file =  open(file_path)
except OSError as e:
    # do something
```

Or even better with python 2.6+ / 3:

```
with open(file_path) as file :
```

It is much better because it's much more generical. You can apply "try / except" to almost anything. You don't need to care about what to do to prevent it, just about the error you are risking.

**Do not check against type**

Python is dynamically typed, therefore checking for type makes you lose flexibility. Instead, use duck typing by checking behavior. E.G, you expect a string in a function, then use str() to convert any object in a string. You expect a list, use list() to convert any iterable in a list.

Don't :

```
def foo(name) :
    if isinstance(name, str) :
        print name.lower()

def bar(listing) :
    if isinstance(listing, list) :
        listing.extend((1, 2, 3))
        return ", ".join(listing)
```

Do :

```
def foo(name) :
    print str(name).lower()

def bar(listing) :
    l = list(listing)
    l.extend((1, 2, 3))
    return ", ".join(l)
```

Using the last way, foo will accept any object. Bar will accept strings, tuples, sets, lists and much more. Cheap DRY :-)

**Don't mix spaces and tabs**

Just don't. You would cry.

**Use *object* as first parent**

This is tricky, but it will bite you as your program grows. There are old and new classes in Python 2.x. The old ones are, well, old. They lack some features, and can have awkward behavior with inheritance. To be usable, any of your class must be of the "new style". To do so, make it inherit from "object" :

Don't :

```
class Father :
    pass

class Child(Father) :
    pass
```

Do :

```
class Father(object) :
    pass


class Child(Father) :
    pass
```

In Python 3.x all classes are new style so you can declare `class Father:` is fine.

**Don't initialize class attributes outside the `__init__` method**

People coming from other languages find it tempting because that what you do the job in Java or PHP. You write the class name, then list your attributes and give them a default value. It seems to work in Python, however, this doesn't work the way you think.

Doing that will setup class attributes (static attributes), then when you will try to get the object attribute, it will gives you its value unless it's empty. In that case it will return the class attributes.

It implies two big hazards :

- If the class attribute is changed, then the initial value is changed.
- If you set a mutable object as a default    value, you'll get the same object shared across instances.

Don't (unless you want static) :

```
class Car(object):
    color = "red"
    wheels = [wheel(), Wheel(), Wheel(), Wheel()]
```

Do :

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = "red"
        self.wheels = [wheel(), Wheel(), Wheel(), Wheel()]
```

Comment: In your "just do it and correct the error" stanza, you have an except: block which is evilbadscary.

Always catch the minimal subset of errors to avoid wierd debugging gotchas in larger programs, so in your example replace

except:

with

except IOError as E: (Always worth grabbing the exception instance for inspection too ;))

Comment: Good summary, you should add a section about avoiding bare excepts though. It's perhaps the single most dangerous thing to do.

Comment: list(listing).append("test") - this is useless, the new list is unaccessible.

Comment: You are right, this is just a typo. Fixed. Of course it doesn't work if you expect the list to be updated outside the function. But in Python, you usually don't use fonction with side effects. There are methods to manipulate mutable types.

Comment: "It is much better because it's much more generical" - Even better the file is closed automatically :)

Comment: Most of these are quite general programming gotchas: they are not very specific to Python.

Comment: You mean that the 'object' issue is not a Python only issue? You can do "if var is None" in C (which is NOT null)? Or use ducktyping instead of isinstance in Java? Or that you really othen use "try / except" as normal flow control keywords in any other language?

Comment: The class attributes paragraph is confusing.  In the don't section, you illustrate class attributes, and in the do section, you illustrate instance attributes; different things.  Yes, reading a non-existant instance results in reading a same-named class attribute, but the answer doesn't clarify why that's a hazard.

Comment: No, the danger is that self.wheels[0] would be a shared list among all instances if set as class attributes cause any class attribute is used as a default instance attribute. I see all my students creating class attributes while what they want is an instance attribute, because it seems t work with unmutable types.

Comment: So declaring a class attribute outside of a method like __init__() is equivalent to declaring a static class attribute in, say, PHP?

Comment: Yes. With the tricky difference that Python wil return it if the user try to access the instance variable with the same name, except if the instance variable have been set too.

Comment: In most cases it is incorrect to compare directly with `True`, `False`; use `if var`, `if not var` instead that may call `__len__()` or `__nonzero__()` (`__bool__` on Python 3) methods. Always use `if var is None` instead of `== None` (a class may override `__eq__` method).

Answer (score 39):

When you need a population of arrays you might be tempted to type something like this:

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3,4,5]]*4
```

And sure enough it will give you what you expect when you look at it

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(a)

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

But don't expect the elements of your population to be seperate objects:

```
>>> a[0][0] = 2
>>> pprint(a)

[[2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Unless this is what you need...

It is worth mentioning a workaround:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5] for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: I would not use _ in the expression.  First it has a special meaning to the interactive interpreter.  Second, it's not totally obvious that what you mean is that you are ignoring the loop variable.  how about changing it to `ignored` or some such?

Comment: I would just use 'i' for that variable.

Comment: What does _ mean to the interpreter?

Comment: In the interactive interpreter _ is the output of your last command.

Comment: Questions related to this pitfall are posted periodically. Here is a commonly cited dupe target: http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/190597

Answer (score 28):

Python Language Gotchas -- things that fail in very obscure ways

- Using mutable default arguments.
- Leading zeroes mean octal.  `09` is a very obscure syntax error in Python 2.x
- Misspelling overridden method names in a superclass or subclass.  The superclass misspelling mistake is worse, because none of the subclasses override it correctly.

Python Design Gotchas

- Spending time on introspection (e.g. trying to automatically determine types or superclass identity or other stuff).  First, it's obvious from reading the source.  More importantly, time spent on weird Python introspection usually indicates a fundamental failure to grasp polymorphism.  80% of the Python introspection questions on SO are failure to get Polymorphism.
- Spending time on code golf.  Just because your mental model of your application is four keywords ("do", "what", "I", "mean"), doesn't mean you should build a hyper-complex introspective decorator-driven framework to do that.  Python allows you to take DRY to a level that is silliness.  The rest of the Python introspection questions on SO attempts to reduce complex problems to code golf exercises.
- Monkeypatching.
- Failure to actually read through the standard library, and reinventing the wheel.
- Conflating interactive type-as-you go Python with a proper program.  While you're typing interactively, you may lose track of a variable and have to use `globals()`.  Also, while you're typing, almost everything is global.  In proper programs, you'll never "lose track of" a variable, and nothing will be global.

Comment: What other alternatives are there for MonkeyPatching when 3rd part lib has some bug?

Comment: It's python: you have the source.  If 3rd party lib has a bug, you can just fix it.

Comment: Python 3.0 fixes the leading-zeros-octal bug.  Leading zeros on a numeral no longer make it octal.  You may still use octal literals however with a 0o (zero small-oh) prefix.

Comment: I wouldn't say leading zero is a bug - it's a feature. It's just a little surprising for those who have never seen a PDP11.

Comment: Does Python run on a PDP11? I used to program a VAX, which is like a super duper PDP11. Even then, I hated octal.

Comment: Python runs on Unix; Unix was originally developed for a PDP-11.  There's a small chance that you could get it to work.

Comment: @Chris: "Fixes"? Wow, what a stupid decision by the python folk. Break all programs that call chmod!

Comment: @Draemon: Only if you didn't follow the docs.  http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chmod.  Says to build the mode using the supplied constants, not a magical octal constant.

Comment: What S. Lott said about fixing, but please also remember to send a description of the bug (and the fix, if you have it) to the maintainer of the 3rd-party library.

Comment: There's now a pip package that does a great job of helping to mitigate misspellings in overridden method names: https://pypi.org/project/overrides/

Answer (score 27):

Mutating a default argument:

```
def foo(bar=[]):
    bar.append('baz')
    return bar
```

The default value is evaluated only once, and not every time the function is called. Repeated calls to `foo()` would return `['baz']`, `['baz', 'baz']`, `['baz', 'baz', 'baz']`, ...

If you want to mutate bar do something like this:

```
def foo(bar=None):
    if bar is None:
        bar = []

    bar.append('baz')
    return bar
```

Or, if you like arguments to be final:

```
def foo(bar=[]):
    not_bar = bar[:]

    not_bar.append('baz')
    return not_bar
```

Comment: Also, mutating a class attribute. Same reason, similar effects.

Comment: +1 I got burned by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959113/python-function-calls-are-bleeding-scope-stateful-failing-to-initialize-paramet

Answer (score 22):

I don't know whether this is a common mistake, but while Python doesn't have increment and decrement operators, double signs are allowed, so

```
++i
```

and

```
--i
```

is syntactically correct code, but doesn't do anything "useful" or that you may be expecting.

Comment: Should probably note that python increment/decrement is done with i += 1, i -= 1.  (Inplace of ++i, ==i or i++, i--).

Comment: Wow, never new that. How can this be syntactically correct? I'm confused.

Comment: The relevant production rule of the python grammar is

u_expr ::=  power | "-" u_expr | "+" u_expr | "~" u_expr

(See http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations)

Comment: The whole point is, that '--' and '++' here are *not* in-/decrement operators but are doubled signs for the following numbers. Hence `--i` is equivalent to `-(-i) == i`. Therefore you can also write `---i = -i`, which is the reason, why Python has no in-/decrement operators. (You would have undefined behaviour, if it had.)

Answer (score 18):

Rolling your own code before looking in the standard library. For example, writing this:

```
def repeat_list(items):
    while True:
        for item in items:
            yield item
```

When you could just use this:

```
from itertools import cycle
```

Examples of frequently overlooked modules (besides [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)) include:

- [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) for creating command line parsers
- [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) for reading configuration files in a standard manner
- [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) for creating and managing temporary files
- [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) for storing Python objects to disk, handy when a full fledged database is overkill

Comment: I would add shutil and glob to that list

Comment: shelve is a very bad example, it is not for portable code between different OS

Comment: [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) is deprecated. Please use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead.

Answer (score 15):

Avoid using keywords as your own identifiers.

Also, it's always good to not use `from somemodule import *`.

Comment: specifically I would avoid using `from ... import *` in modules.  In top level scripts I think it's just fine.

Answer (score 14):

Surprised that nobody said this:

> Mix tab and spaces when indenting.

Really, it's a killer. Believe me. *In particular*, if it runs.

Comment: @e-satis: Not if you read the answers chronologically.

Comment: easy solution: start the source with #!/usr/bin/env python -t

Answer (score 14):

Not using functional tools.  This isn't just a mistake from a style standpoint, it's a mistake from a speed standpoint because a lot of the functional tools are optimized in C.

This is the most common example:

```
temporary = []
for item in itemlist:
    temporary.append(somefunction(item))
itemlist = temporary
```

The correct way to do it:

```
itemlist = map(somefunction, itemlist)
```

The just as correct way to do it:

```
itemlist = [somefunction(x) for x in itemlist]
```

And if you only need the processed items available one at a time, rather than all at once, you can save memory and improve speed by using the iterable equivalents

```
# itertools-based iterator
itemiter = itertools.imap(somefunction, itemlist)
# generator expression-based iterator
itemiter = (somefunction(x) for x in itemlist)
```

Comment: In Python 3.x,`map` from builtins doesn't return a list but an iterator (behaves like `itertools.imap` in Python 2.x). To get a list from `map` you have to use `list(map(...))`.

Answer (score 13):

If you're coming from C++, realize that variables declared in a class definition are static.  You can initialize nonstatic members in the **init** method.

Example:

```
class MyClass:
  static_member = 1

  def __init__(self):
    self.non_static_member = random()
```

Answer (score 10):

[Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)

Comment: hmm that is more about what to do , not what NOT to do

Answer (score 9):

Normal copying (assigning) is done by reference, so filling a container by adapting the same object and inserting, ends up with a container with references to the last added object.

Use `copy.deepcopy` instead.

Comment: It is worth noting that ``a=[["foo"]]; b=copy.deepcopy(a);id(a[0][0]) == id(b[0][0]))`` the string ``foo`` is the same string object. You can't copy a string. It's interned and it's immutable, so it makes sense that there is nothing to copy anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Importing `re` and using the full regular expression approach to string matching/transformation, when perfectly good [string methods](http://python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html) exist for every common operation (e.g. capitalisation, simple matching/searching).

Comment: And capitalisation, isalpha etc etc are all handled better by unicode methods than any regexp you can ever aticipate write, given how many different letters and symbols there are in unicode.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `%s` formatter in error messages. In almost every circumstance, `%r` should be used.

For example, imagine code like this:

```
try:
    get_person(person)
except NoSuchPerson:
    logger.error("Person %s not found." %(person))
```

Printed this error:

```
ERROR: Person wolever not found.
```

It's impossible to tell if the `person` variable is the string `"wolever"`, the unicode string `u"wolever"` or an instance of the `Person` class (which has `__str__` defined as `def __str__(self): return self.name`). Whereas, if `%r` was used, there would be three different error messages:

```
...
logger.error("Person %r not found." %(person))
```

Would produce the much more helpful errors:

```
ERROR: Person 'wolever' not found.
ERROR: Person u'wolever' not found.
ERROR: Person  not found.
```

Another good reason for this is that paths are a whole lot easier to copy/paste. Imagine:

```
try:
    stuff = open(path).read()
except IOError:
    logger.error("Could not open %s" %(path))
```

If `path` is `some path/with 'strange' "characters"`, the error message will be:

```
ERROR: Could not open some path/with 'strange' "characters"
```

Which is hard to visually parse and hard to copy/paste into a shell.

Whereas, if `%r` is used, the error would be:

```
ERROR: Could not open 'some path/with \'strange\' "characters"'
```

Easy to visually parse, easy to copy-paste, all around better.

Comment: Personnaly, I prefer using the "{0}".format(person) rather that "%r" % person. I think it is much more capable. More over the Python doc says: "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3.0, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code."

Comment: True that the new `.format` is better, but I think you've missed the point of what I'm saying: I'm saying that, when you're printing diagnostic information, `repr`'d messages are much more helpful then straight `str`'d messages (eg, using `{0!r}` instead of `{0}`.

Answer (score 7):

- don't write large output messages to standard output
- strings are immutable - build them not using "+" operator but rather
  using str.join() function.
- read those articles:

  - [python gotchas](http://www.ferg.org/projects/python_gotchas.html)
  - [things to avoid](http://www.techiesabode.com/article/read_article_w.php?article_id=14)
  - [Gotchas for Python users](http://boo.codehaus.org/Gotchas+for+Python+Users)
  - [Python Landmines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530530/python-2-x-gotchas-and-landmines)

Last link is the original one, this SO question is an duplicate.

Comment: another alternative to `str.join` is `str.format` which can be very helpful down the road when you need to localize your strings.

Answer (score 6):

I would stop using deprecated methods in 2.6, so that your app or script will be ready and easier to convert to Python 3.

Answer (score 6):

A bad habit I had to train myself out of was using `X and Y or Z` for inline logic.

Unless you can 100% always guarantee that `Y` will be a true value, even when your code changes in 18 months time, you set yourself up for some unexpected behaviour.

Thankfully, in later versions you can use `Y if X else Z`.

Comment: the work around for older python versions without the conditional operator is `(X and [y] or [z])[0]`

Comment: Prefixing with `not not` is an ugly trick to make sure it's boolean. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Some personal opinions, but I find it best **NOT** to:

- use deprecated modules (use warnings for them)
- overuse classes and inheritance (typical of static languages legacy maybe)
- explicitly use declarative algorithms (as iteration with `for` vs use of 
  `itertools`)
- reimplement functions from the standard lib, "because I don't need all of those features"
- using features for the sake of it (reducing compatibility with older Python versions)
- using metaclasses when you really don't have to and more generally make things too "magic"
- avoid using generators
- (more personal) try to micro-optimize CPython code on a low-level basis. Better spend time on algorithms and then optimize by making a small C shared lib called by `ctypes` (it's so easy to gain 5x perf boosts on an inner loop)
- use unnecessary lists when iterators would suffice
- code a project directly for 3.x before the libs you need are all available (this point may be a bit controversial now!)

Answer (score 5):

`++n` and `--n` may not work as expected by people coming from C or Java background.

`++n` is positive of a positive number, which is simply `n`.

`--n` is negative of a negative number, which is simply `n`.

Answer (score 5):

I've started learning Python as well and one of the bigest mistakes I made is constantly using C++/C# indexed "for" loop. Python have for(i ; i < length ; i++) type loop and for a good reason - most of the time there are better ways to do there same thing.

Example:
I had a method that iterated over a list and returned the indexes of selected items:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i].selected:
        retVal.append(i)
```

Instead Python has list comprehension that solves the same problem in a more elegant and easy to read way:

```
retVal = [index for index, item in enumerate(myList) if item.selected]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import this
```

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

```
import not_this
```

Write ugly code.
Write implicit code.
Write complex code.
Write nested code.
Write dense code.
Write unreadable code.
Write special cases.
Strive for purity.
Ignore errors and exceptions.
Write optimal code before releasing.
Every implementation needs a flowchart.
Don't use namespaces.

Comment: For a second I thought there was another easter egg in the stdlib that I hadn't known about; but then I tried import not_this and got an ImportError

Answer (score 4):

Never assume that having a multi-threaded Python application and a SMP capable machine (for instance one equipped with a multi-core CPU) will give you the benefit of introducing true parallelism into your application. Most likely it will not because of GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which synchronizes your application on the byte-code interpreter level.

There are some workarounds like taking advantage of SMP by putting the concurrent code in  C API calls or using multiple processes (instead of threads) via wrappers (for instance like the one available at http://www.parallelpython.org) but if one needs true multi-threading in Python one should look at things like Jython, IronPython etc. (GIL is a feature of the CPython interpreter so other implementations are not affected).

According to Python 3000 FAQ (available at Artima) the above still stands even for the latest Python versions.

Comment: CPython has "True multithreading". What it doesn't have, thanks to the GIL, are threats that can be used for load balancing. But then again, threads where never intended for that. Threads were designed so that you could have locking calls without creating separate processes. However, with Unix and Javas heavy threads, load balancing with threads have become possible, and many people seem to think that this is how you "should" do it.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase 'True multithreading' as 'SMP capable multi-threading'.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat related to the default mutable argument, how one checks for the "missing" case results in differences when an empty list is passed:

```
def func1(toc=None):
    if not toc:
        toc = []
    toc.append('bar')

def func2(toc=None):
    if toc is None:
        toc = []
    toc.append('bar')

def demo(toc, func):
    print func.__name__
    print '  before:', toc
    func(toc)
    print '  after:', toc

demo([], func1)
demo([], func2)
```

Here's the output:

```
func1
  before: []
  after: []
func2
  before: []
  after: ['bar']
```

Comment: A clearer way to say this is to say "When checking for None, use `is None` instead of `not`", as it's not only for missing cases, but any None testing.

Answer (score 3):

The very first mistake before you even start: *don't be afraid of whitespace*.

When you show someone a piece of Python code, they are impressed until you tell them that they *have* to indent correctly. For some reason, most people feel that a language shouldn't force a certain style on them while all of them will indent the code nonetheless.

Comment: Funny thing is, I wouldn't ever touch somebody's nasty Java code with all that shi* everywhere, and incorrect indentation. It's so terrible to read. I have always indented correctly, so when I picked up Python it was like a god-sent.

Comment: absolutely, and one of the byproducts of strict indentation is that everybody's code looks the same.

Answer (score 3):

Common pitfall: *default arguments are evaluated once*:

```
def x(a, l=[]):
    l.append(a)
    return l

print x(1)
print x(2)
```

prints:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
```

i.e. you always get the same list.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_variable = <something>
...
my_varaible = f(my_variable)
...
use my_variable and thinking it contains the result from f, and not the initial value
```

Python won't warn you in any way that on the second assignment you misspelled the variable name and created a new one.

Comment: A simple rule to avoid this: "a variable with a particular name must always contain comparable values". For example, `breakfast` could contain `spam()` or `eggs()`, but it could not contain `[spam(), eggs()]` or `"spam"`.

Comment: It's especially important, I've found, when dealing with strings. For example, `person = "joe"; person = get_person_by_name(person)` is bad, but can be avoided by simply using: `person_name = "joe"; person = get_person_by_name(person_name)`

Answer (score 3):

You've mentioned default arguments... One that's almost as bad as mutable default arguments: default values which aren't `None`.

Consider a function which will cook some food:

```
def cook(breakfast="spam"):
    arrange_ingredients_for(breakfast)
    heat_ingredients_for(breakfast)
    serve(breakfast)
```

Because it specifies a default value for `breakfast`, it is impossible for some other function to say "cook your default breakfast" without a special-case:

```
def order(breakfast=None):
    if breakfast is None:
        cook()
    else:
        cook(breakfast)
```

However, this could be avoided if `cook` used `None` as a default value:

```
def cook(breakfast=None):
    if breakfast is None:
        breakfast = "spam"

def order(breakfast=None):
    cook(breakfast)
```

A good example of this is Django bug [#6988](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6988). Django's caching module had a "save to cache" function which looked like this:

```
def set(key, value, timeout=0):
    if timeout == 0:
        timeout = settings.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
    _caching_backend.set(key, value, timeout)
```

But, for the memcached backend, a timeout of `0` means "never timeout"… Which, as you can see, would be impossible to specify.

Comment: +1 for arguing for nothing(none) :00

Answer (score 3):

Don't modify a list while iterating over it.

```
odd = lambda x : bool(x % 2)
numbers = range(10)
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if odd(numbers[i]):
        del numbers[i]
```

One common suggestion to work around this problem is to iterate over the list in reverse:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)-1,0,-1):
    if odd(numbers[i]):
        del numbers[i]
```

But even better is to use a list comprehension to build a new list to replace the old:

```
numbers[:] = [n for n in numbers if not odd(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a local module with the same name as one from the stdlib.  This is almost always done by accident (as reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753552/has-twisted-changed-its-dependencies)), but usually results in cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 1):

### Promiscuous Exception Handling

This is something that I see a surprising amount in production code and it makes me cringe.

```
try:
    do_something() # do_something can raise a lot errors e.g. files, sockets
except:
    pass # who cares we'll just ignore it
```

Was the exception the one you want suppress, or is it more serious? But there are more subtle cases. That can make you pull your hair out trying to figure out.

```
try: 
    foo().bar().baz()
except AttributeError: # baz() may return None or an incompatible *duck type*
    handle_no_baz()
```

The problem is foo or baz could be the culprits too. I think this can be more insidious in that this is *idiomatic python* where you are checking your types for proper methods. But each method call has chance to return something unexpected and suppress bugs that should be raising exceptions.

Knowing what exceptions a method can throw are not always obvious. For example, urllib and urllib2 use socket which has its own exceptions that percolate up and rear their ugly head when you least expect it.

Exception handling is a productivity boon in handling errors over system level languages like C. But I have found suppressing exceptions improperly can create truly mysterious debugging sessions and take away a major advantage interpreted languages provide.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to mutable default arguments is the mutable class attribute.

```
>>> class Classy:
...    foo = []
...    def add(self, value):
...        self.foo.append(value)
... 
>>> instance1 = Classy()
>>> instance2 = Classy()
>>> instance1.add("Foo!")
>>> instance2.foo
['Foo!']
```

Not what you expect.

Comment: I'd say exactly what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, once you understand what's going on, yes. As a Python newbie, no...

Comment: I would say the mistake there is referring to Classy.foo as self.foo. In Java, you'll get a compiler warning for "referring to a static variable in a non-static way" or something. I forget if Python does the same but it definitely should. If you refer to it in a way that it doesn't look like an instance variable, there's no surprise.

Comment: It's true it removes the surprise, but it also means you can't override foo in instances, which you can do if you refer to it via self. And that's really handy.

Answer (score 0):

This has been mentioned already, but I'd like to elaborate a bit on class attribute mutability.

When you define a member attribute, then every time you instance that class it gets an attribute that's a shallow copy of the class attribute.

So if you have something like

```
class Test(object):
   myAttr = 1
instA = Test()
instB = Test()
instB.myAttr = 2
```

It will behave as expected.

```
>>> instA.myAttr
  1
>>> instB.myAttr
  2
```

The problem comes when you have class attributes that are mutable.  Since instantiation just did a shallow copy, all instances are going to just have a reference pointing to the same object.

```
class Test(object):
   myAttr=[1,2,3]
instA = Test()
instB = Test()
instB.myAttr[0]=2
>>> instA.myAttr
   [2,2,3]
```

But the references *are* actual members of the instance, so as long as you are actually assigning something new to the attribute you are ok.

You can get around this by making a deep copy of mutable variables during the **init** function

```
import copy
class Test(object):
   myAttr = [1,2,3]
   def __init__(self):
      self.myAttr = copy.deepcopy(self.myAttr)
instA = Test()
instB = Test()
instB.myAttr[0] = 5
>>> instA.myAttr
   [1,2,3]
>>> instB.myAttr
   [5,2,3]
```

It might be possible to write a decorator that would automatically deepcopy all your class attributes during init, but I don't know offhand of one that is provided anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm blogs has a good post about Python performance issues and how to avoid them:
[10 Python Optimization Tips and Issues](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/index.php/programming/python/10-python-optimization-tips-and-issues/)

Answer (score 0):

### Class attributes

Some answers above are incorrect or unclear about class attributes.

They do not become instance attributes, but are readable using the same syntax as instance attributes.  They can be changed by accessing them via the class name.

```
class MyClass:
    attrib = 1                         # class attributes named 'attrib'
    another = 2                        # and 'another'
    def __init__(self):
        self.instattr = 3              # creates instance attributes
        self.attrib = 'instance'      

mc0 = MyClass()
mc1 = MyClass()

print mc.attrib    # 'instance'
print mc.another   # '2'

MyClass.another = 5  # change class attributes
MyClass.attrib = 21  # <- masked by instance attribute of same name

print mc.attrib    # 'instance'   unchanged instance attribute
print mc.another   # '5'          changed class attribute
```

Class attributes can be used as sort of default values for instance attributes, masked later by instance attributes of the same name with a different value.

### Intermediate scope local variables

A more difficult matter to understand is the scoping of variables in nested functions.

In the following example, *y* is unwritable from anywhere other than function 'outer'.  *x* is readable and writable from anywhere, as it is declared global in each function.  *z* is readable and writable in 'inner*' only.  *y* is readable in 'outer' and 'inner*', 
but not writable except in 'outer'.

```
x = 1
def outer():
    global x
    y = 2
    def inner1():
        global x, y
        y = y+1  # creates new global variable with value=3
    def inner2():
        global x
        y = y+1  # creates new local variable with value=3
```

I believe that Python 3 includes an 'outer' keyword for such 'outside this function but not global' cases.  In Python 2.#, you are stuck with either making *y* global, or making it a mutable parameter to 'inner'.

Comment: For python3 there is ``nonlocal`` if you want to modify y in one of the ``innerX`` function, and **reflect** that change in the ``outer`` function.