# Importing library classes in Python

Tags: python, exception, import

I have following project hierarchy:

```
project_dir
  lib
    __init__.py
    ...
    some_script.py
    ...
    agent
      __init__.py
      ...
      errors.py
      some_agent_script.py
      ...
```

There is the SomeException class definition in lib/agent/erros.py
I use following code to import them inside lib/agent/some_agent_script.py:

```
from errors import SomeException
```

Also I use following code to import in lib/some_script.py

```
from agent.errors import SomeException
```

The problem is when I raise a SomeException in lib/agent/some_agent_script.py then lib/some_script.py can not catch it in an except block:

```
try:
    # Here comes a call to lib/agent/some_agent_script.py function
    # that raises SomeException
except SomeException, exc:
    # Never goes here
    print(exc)
except Exception, exc:
    print(exc.__class__.__name__) # prints "SomeException"

    # Let's print id's
    print(id(exc.__class__))
    print(id(SomeException))
    # They are different!

    # Let's print modules list
    pprint.pprint(sys.modules)
```

I can see in sys.modules that erros module was imported twice: the first is with 'agent.errors' key and the second is with 'lib.agent.errors' key

The following code goes right, but it's not a beautiful solution:

```
agent_errors = sys.modules.get('agent.errors')
from agent_errors import SomeException

try:
    # Here comes a call to lib/agent/some_agent_script.py function
except SomeException:
    print('OK')
```

What should I do to make this module not to import twice?

Comment: Related reading: [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459236/module-reimported-if-imported-from-different-path), [PEP 395](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/)

Comment: That's why they introduced relative imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use fully qualified imports.

```
from lib.agent.errors import SomeException
```

Do this in every module that uses it. Then it will always have the same package name. 
You should probably also change the top-level package name. The name "lib" is too generic.

This will also save you some headaches if you happen to name a module the same as a base, or "stock", module. For example, suppose you created a module `lib/agent/socket.py` and in `lib/agent/some_agent_script.py` you wrote `import socket`. You would not actually get your module, but the stock one.

So it's better to get in the habit of always using fully qualified package names, off a common root if you can.

An alternative is to use absolute imports.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import .errors
```

Note the leading dot. This explicitly imports from the current package. It should also fix your problem, but I admit I haven't tried it.

Comment: Sounds good, but lib/agent is a library which is being used in several projects. It's not good to specify fully qualified name there, cause in other projects agent can be located not in lib module.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed! There is an addition: it is nesessary to use absolute_import in both modules - which are raising and handling an exception.

Comment: @fey Cool. Yes, all `__future__` imports only affect the module they are in.