# Python instances and attributes: is this a bug or i got it totally wrong?

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

Suppose you have something like this:

```
class intlist:
        def __init__(self,l = []):
                self.l = l
        def add(self,a):
                self.l.append(a)

def appender(a):
        obj = intlist()
        obj.add(a)
        print obj.l

if __name__ == "__main__":
        for i in range(5):
                appender(i)
```

A function creates an instance of intlist and calls on this fresh instance the method append on the instance attribute l.

How comes the output of this code is:

[0]

[0, 1]

[0, 1, 2]

[0, 1, 2, 3]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

?
If i switch

```
obj = intlist()
```

with

```
obj = intlist(l=[])
```

I get the desired output

[0]

[1]

[2]

[3]

[4]

Why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for wording this like a question and admitting fault from the get-go. That's how we learn! :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011431/python-things-one-must-avoid

Comment: Thank you all, now i got it, i must pay more attention at what i use as default value. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, you've hit one of the common Python gotchas: default values are computed once, then re-used. So, every time `__init__` is called, the *same* list is being used.

This is the Pythonic way of doing what you want:

```
def __init__(self, l=None):
    self.l = [] if l is None else l
```

For a bit more information, check out [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) (especially about three paragraphs after that heading).

**Edit**: There is [a much better description in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402887/python-instances-and-attributes-is-this-a-bug-or-i-got-it-totally-wrong/2402940#2402940).

Comment: Right. In general you probably do not want to use mutable types as default values.

Comment: Just a little note: In my initial answer, I used `self.l = l or []`… Which is, in this case, probably correct, but it's a dangerous habit (for example, this: `my_list = []; intlist(my_list); my_list.append(4)` might not do what you want).

Comment: +1: Standard problem -- mutable objects as default values.  See all of these for explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+mutable+default+values

Answer (score 4):

When you set the default value of `l=[]` in `__init__`, you're actually using the same list each time. Instead, you could try something like:

```
class intlist:
    def __init__(self, l=None):
        if l is None:
            self.l = []
        else:
            self.l = l
```

Comment: +1, `is None` is exactly the right way to check here (not `== None` or checks simply based on the truth value of `l` as other answers suggest!).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that when you are saying

```
def __init__(self,l = []):
```

You are telling Python to use the same list, `[]`, for each invocation of the constructor. So each time `obj = intlist()` is called the same list is appended to.

What you should do instead is set `l` to a default value of `None`, which is a scalar (so your code will work as expected if it is used multiple times). Then, if `l` is `None`, initialize a new class member as `[]`. Otherwise just assign the member variable to `l`.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior occurs because all calls to your `__init__` method share the same default list.

Try:

```
class intlist:
        def __init__(self, l):
                self.l = l if (l is not None) else []
        def add(self,a):
                self.l.append(a)
```

EDIT: Use `is not`, per SilentGhost

Comment: `is` is an idiomatic testing for `None`

Answer (score 1):

`obj = intlist()` calls your `__init__()` function which uses the same array for every instance of the class.

`obj = intlist(l=[])` creates a new array for every instance.

Answer (score 1):

For more information I suggest reading this: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with default parameters of types like lists and dicts. Each instance of intlist gets that same list object from the default parameter.