# Has Twisted changed its dependencies?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm currently working on a Python/Twisted project which is to be distributed and tested on Planetlab. For some reason my code was working on friday and now that I wanted to test a minor change it refuses to work at all:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "acn_a4/src/node.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/twisted/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.python import compat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/compat.py", line 146, in <module>
    import operator
  File "/home/cdecker/dev/acn/acn_a4/src/operator.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/cdecker/acn_a4/src/node.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 20, in <module>
    from twisted.python import log, failure, components
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/log.py", line 19, in <module>
    from twisted.python import util, context, reflect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/util.py", line 5, in <module>
    import os, sys, hmac, errno, new, inspect, warnings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/inspect.py", line 32, in <module>
    from operator import attrgetter
ImportError: cannot import name attrgetter
```

And since I'm pretty new to python I have no idea what could have caused this problem.

All suggestions are welcome :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of your own files, `/home/cdecker/dev/acn/acn_a4/src/operator.py` shadows Python's builtin `operator` module. You should rename your own `operator.py` to something else.

You can see the problem here:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Twisted-10.0.0-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/compat.py", line 146, in <module>
import operator
File "/home/cdecker/dev/acn/acn_a4/src/operator.py", line 7, in <module>
```

Twisted tries to `import operator` but Python loads one of your own modules.

To prevent stuff like that in the future you should probably not add your src folder to the PYTHONPATH like that. Create a package instead, so that your own files appear as `myproject.mymodule` and can't shadow builtins.

Answer (score 1):

`ImportError` is raised on `import` statement when a name cannot be imported, because module or package or name doesn't exists. In your case `attrgetter` doesn't exists in `operator` module.

The first idea is that you define a module called `operator` in the project's main directory. Modules, or packages, are searched following `sys.path` order, if you define a module with the same name in your main directory, you are hiding all others module with the same name in the search path.