# Python list of lists

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected feature in a Python list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists)

I want to make a list of lists in Python, but apparently this doesn't work, as changing one number changes several. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
>>> a = [[0]*3]*4
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Dont use `*`. It makes copies. Use list comprehension instead

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yup, I've voted to close this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you've discovered is a [classic Python pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025447/190597).

`x = [0]*3` is a list. No problem there, but `[x]*4` creates a list with 4 references to the exact same list `x`. So modifying the first element, `x`, also modifies the other elements as well.

Instead, if you do this:

```
In [193]: a = [[0]*3 for i in range(4)]
```

then you get 4 distinct items in the list:

```
In [194]: a[0][0] = 1

In [195]: a
Out[195]: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: StackOverflow needs the ability to bookmark an answer.  This is a prime example for why.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco: Star the question.

Comment: I starred the question. I want to star the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, `[x]*n` creates a new list with `n` references to `x`. This is perfectly good to have if `x` is immutable (string, tuple, etc.), but it gets rather confusing if `x` is mutable since changes to one element affect `x`, and thus appear to affect all elements of the list.

So, the solution is to use a list comprehension to create `n` new things:

```
[x for _ in xrange(n)] # we use _ here as a "dummy variable"
```

In your case, it would look like

```
a = [[0]*3 for _ in xrange(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `*`. Use list comprehension and  create like:

```
>>> a = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

See unutbu and nneonneo's answer for better explanation.

Comment: Actually, it would be nice if `*` made copies. The correct thing to say is that it does *not* make copies, only extra references.

Comment: hmm, I have read your answer; nice. Removed the statement.

Answer (score -1):

When using `*` in list's it creates copies, so when you do `a[0][0]=1` all other sub-list's copy this.

In order to fix this, use a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to create your list.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that it *doesn't* make copies, not that it does.