# Why is Python 3.12 constant-valued expression in loop not same as variable of same value?

Tags: python, list

Using constant-valued expressions in a loop is considered bad practice in most languages I've ever used, but it seems that Python insists I do that; otherwise, the results are not correct:

First, the problem method:

```
def make_2d_grid() -> list[list[int]]:
    grid: list[list[int]] = []
    single_row = [0] * 8
    print(f'{type(single_row)=}, {single_row=}')
    for i in range(8):
        # grid.append(single_row) # using the variable produces different results - why?
        if i == 0:
            print(f'{type([0] * 8)=}')
        grid.append([0] * 8) # constant-valued expression repeated in a loop - BAD PRACTICE - but it works correctly

    print(f'{grid=}')
    return grid
```

The code that calls the above and manipulates the list that is returned:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list2d = make_2d_grid()
    print(f'{list2d=}')
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            if i < 3 or i > 4:
                list2d[i][j] = 1

    print(f'{list2d=}')
```

If I try to use the variable `single_row` instead of the constant-valued expression, the call to the above method results in incorrect results in the form of a completely different set of rows and columns being populated with a 1 instead of the first three and the last three rows of the 2d-list (a.k.a., grid):

The two items, `single_row` and the constant-valued expression `[0] * 8`, ***should*** be identical, but the results using the constant-valued expression are correct while the use of the variable `single_row` cause the subsequent code to ***populate a completely different set of rows and columns*** with a 1 instead of just the first three and the last three rows of the 2d-list (a.k.a., grid).

What I need help understanding is why my noble attempt to not use a constant-valued expression in a loop results in a data structure that does not perform the same as when the loop uses the constant-valued expression.

The output of the above when using the constant-valued expression in a loop, which is correct/expected:

```
type(single_row)=<class 'list'>, single_row=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
type([0] * 8)=<class 'list'>
grid=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
list2d=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
list2d=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The output of the above when using the variable `single_row` in the loop, which is incorrect/unexpected:

```
type(single_row)=<class 'list'>, single_row=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
type([0] * 8)=<class 'list'>
grid=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
list2d=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
list2d=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This should have been a simple swap of a constant-valued expression for an equivalent variable, but based on the different outputs, they are not.   Why aren't they the same?

********* UPDATE 1**********

As part of my self-education on Python pointers, I modified my original code and proved to myslef that the ***pointer*** to a list originally stored in variable `single_row` was the problem when it came to indexing through the 8 row x 8 column grid.

When you run the code, it will show how `single_row` is slowly modified instead of the expectation that each row and column of variable `list2d` is being modified.

Even if Python does not ***explicitly*** claim to support what other languages call *pointers*, it sure ***seems*** to ***implicitly*** use pointers whether desired or not.

If it quacks like a duck ....

```
def make_2d_grid() -> list[list[int]]:
    grid: list[list[int]] = []
    single_row = [0] * 8
    for i in range(8):
        grid.append(single_row)
    print(f'{grid=}')
    return (grid, single_row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = make_2d_grid()
    list2d = results[0]
    single_row = results[1]
    print(f'{list2d=}')
    print(f'{single_row=}')
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            if i < 3 or i > 4:
                list2d[i][j] = 1
                print(f'{single_row=}')

    print(f'{list2d=}')
```

********* UPDATE 2 *********
As further proof that Python has "underneath the covers" pointers, I made a slight change that does what I want by applying the .copy() operation to the variable `single_row`:

```
def make_2d_grid() -> list[list[int]]:
    grid: list[list[int]] = []
    single_row = [0] * 8
    for i in range(8):
        grid.append(single_row.copy())
    print(f'{grid=}')
    return grid
```

I'm sure many will fight me on this "python has pointers" issue, but it is as clear as the nose on my face that python does use pointers, even if they are not directly manipulatable (for now, in the future, who knows?) in code.

Comment: `single_value` isn't referenced anywhere in your code. (This _smells_ like a very common mistake, caused by forgetting that copying a reference to a list just creates a new reference, not a new list; but it's hard enough to follow that I'm currently having trouble being certain that's the actual issue at hand)

Comment: The point is that I __cannot__ use the variable `single_value` in the loop to append to the grid because I wind up with the wrong results.  Python forces me to use the constant-valued expression in a loop, which in every language I have ever used was considered bad practice to the point some higher-end IDE's would display a yellow warning flag next to such violations and offer to "extract constant-valued expression into variable" as part of the IDE's built-in refactoring capabilities.

Comment: Then show that: show the code that doesn't work, so others can confirm that.

Comment: When you append `single_row` to `grid` multiple times, you're appending **references** to **the same list** object, NOT copies of it. Thus, modifying any element of any row actually modifies the same, single list object, reflected across all references to it in grid. This leads to the "unexpected" behavior when using `single_row`.

Comment: The entire set of code is displayed in the original post.  The code that does not work has comments such as the following:

grid.append(single_row) # using the variable produces different results - why?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994303/python-list-of-lists or actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Thanks to Marcin Orlowski, the answer boils down to appending a __pointer to a single list 8 times vs 8. instances of unique instances of a list__.

Comment: `[0]*8` isn't a constant valued expression. It creates a new list every time it runs. `single_row` is a single list and if you append it multiple times, its still that one single list referenced multiple times.

Comment: "cannot use the variable `single_value`" -- where in your code do you have an example _trying_ to use a variable named `single_value` for anything? You have a `single_row` variable, but _I can't find any `single_value` variable at all_.

Comment: ("pointer to a single list 8 times" -- that's what I told you in the very first comment: "This _smells_ like a very common mistake, caused by forgetting that copying a reference to a list just creates a new reference, not a new list")

Comment: Thank you Charles Duffy.  Sometimes, when you know a dozen or so languages and shift back and forth between 3 or 4 of them quickly, sifting through how they handle pointers can be somewhat challenging.

Comment: @user3785010 well, that can be simplified in Python because Python doesn't have pointers :) and the semantics here are exactly the same as in many commonly used languages, e.g. JS, Java, Ruby.

Comment: it is precisely because it *doesn't* quack like a duck that there are no pointers. If I had a pointer, I could use pointer arithmetic on it and dereference the pointer.

Comment: For those who refuse to believe Python has pointers, even ones that cannot be directly manipulated in code, why does the following copy a REFERENCE POINTER into the grid:
`
    grid: list[list[int]] = []
    single_row = [0] * 8
    for i in range(8):
        grid.append(single_row)
`
while the following does what I want:
`    grid: list[list[int]] = []
    single_row = [0] * 8
    for i in range(8):
        grid.append(single_row.copy())
`
You can swear on a stack of bibles that Python does not have pointers but all evidence in plain sight to me says otherwise.